# how to convert string data to a class object in java using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am new in java world i am trying to send a JSON object from my jsp page in stringy format and want to  convert it to a class file but i am not able to do so. so far i am writing this code which is not working well for me .

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String newHtmlAttribute = request.getParameter("attribute");
            ObjectMapper jsMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            HtmlProperty newHtmlProperty = new HtmlProperty();
            newHtmlProperty = jsMapper.readValue(newHtmlAttribute,HtmlProperty.class);
            System.out.println(newHtmlAttribute);
        }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was nothing wrong in my code. problem was in the naming conventions followed in JavaScript and Java classes by me.

Answer (score 0):

Using jackson you can convert a json string to a class object and not to a class file. And the same thing you are trying to do in your source code. You are trying to get the json string un-marshalled to a java object of class `HtmlProperty`.

If you want to save the current state of HtmlProperty object then you will have to use `Serialization`. Follow this tutorial to learn how to write a java object to a file:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

Comment: Thank You for correcting me, and from the tutorial whatever i am understanding is that they are writing the string into file and then reading and de-serializing the same file , is there any direct way to converting the string direct to a class object.

Comment: @akshay Your code is already doing the json string to HtmlProperty class object conversion

Comment: Thank you . actually there was problem in the naming conventions i was using different in javascript and different in java classes.. there was nothing wrong in my code.